# SQL Server 2008 - Finding Specific Commands/Calls/Text

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to find an insert statement into a specific table.  Unfortunately, the application isn't mine to begin with, there are over 100 stored procedures in the database, I've stepped through the code writing down every stored procedure name from begining to end of this process and I still cannot find it.  I know that the process has to occur some where because another process that depends on it works properly. I just cant find it.

Is there some sort TSQL that would allow me to search across multiple stored procedures for a specific line of text... more specifically "INSERT INTO [tablename]"

UPDATE

I've tried using:

```
 SELECT routine_name, routine_type  
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES  
 WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%INSERT INTO [tablename]%'
```

Straight out, replacing [tablename] with the name of my table.  This returns 0 rows.

I DO have a procedure with that exact line in it, and I would have assumed that it would have been returned in the above query, but its not bringing back anything at all.

UPDATE #2

After using the redgate sql search tool (using INSERT INTO [tablename]) it returns 1 sp, but i'm still in denial that this is correct due to some of the tsql (at the end of the sp its dropping tables that are still in the database...) (this is where my in-experience at sql shines through)

I still cant find where this is being called from though...

UPDATE #3

I just did a search on the entire solution for 'INSERT INTO [tablename]' to see if they maybe DIDN'T use a stored procedure for this call, and nothing... didn't find it anywhere.

Comment: You should check the triggers too, this insert may be performed from a trigger

Comment: That was one of the first thing I checked... there are no triggers.  Probably should have put that out there in the original question.

Comment: To verify if right proc found insert RAIESERROR statment into body, recompile proc and look if your own error pops up when performing operation, it's right proc. Don't forget to delete raiserror statement when testing finished. Description of RAIESERROR statement on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx

Comment: E.g. raiseerror('Found!', 18, 111)

Comment: I added the RAISEERROR to the sp that it shows the insert in, but i'm pretty sure its not using, and I never got an error.  It's gotta be doing the insert from somewhere else.

Comment: Try to search solution for [tablename] w/o 'insert into' string - it can be constructed dynamically or client code can use table object in insert operation.

Comment: Is database accessed through ADO.NET library?

Comment: Is it possible that the statment is generated, ie. dynamic SQL?

Comment: I made an edit to my answer which may give you a better result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the application is running, try running Profiler to capture the queries executed.  Events to watch are SQL:BatchCompleted, RPC:Completed, and SP:StmtCompleted.

Also note that the "INTO" word is optional for the INSERT statement so also search for just "INSERT [tablename]".

Comment: it turns out that it was running a COMPLETELY different process that was actually doing the calculations... even stepping through it i'm not sure how it works from the .net side... im thinking that it has something to do with a sub report that is linked directly to the stored procedure in the database... i updated the OTHER process and its working now.

Answer (score 5):

Make a stored procedure out of it too!

```
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON

GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

GO 

/*
exec sp_find_procs_containing 'insert into tablename'
*/

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_find_procs_containing]    
@search VARCHAR(100) = ''
AS
SET @search = '%' + @search + '%'
SELECT         ROUTINE_NAME,    ROUTINE_DEFINITION
FROM        
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE        
ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE @search
ORDER BY ROUTINE_NAME

GO
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT routine_name, routine_type 
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
 WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%INSERT INTO [tablename]%'
```

warning: this may take a while. If your system is in heavy production use, don't run it on the entire table, but add some extra condition to search only a bunch of stored routines at a time

## EDIT:

Perhaps you should try something else. Make a text dump of all routines, and use grep to search that. I am sure you can get a [grep for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm). Dumping is easily done with management studio: navigate to the database, right click, and choose tasks > generate scripts.

Comment: Be aware that you'll need escape the square brackets if you use them, something like: LIKE '%INSERT INTO |[tablename|]%' ESCAPE '|'. Unless the square brackets are meant to just highlight it as being a placeholder for the real table name :)

Comment: Oddly enough its not even returning the 1 procedure that I WAS able to find that had the call in it.  Unfortunately that sp isn't being called during this procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM sys.syscomments
WHERE text LIKE '%CREATE PROCEDURE%'
AND text LIKE '%INSERT INTO%'
```

or

```
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME, ROUTINE_DEFINITION 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%INSERT INTO%' 
AND ROUTINE_TYPE='PROCEDURE'
```

2nd one found [here](http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/how-do-i-find-a-stored-procedure-containing-text.html)

Comment: You mean they returned 0 rows?

Comment: Correct... they "worked"... but didn't return what I needed so they didn't "work" for me ><

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the previous answers which I won't repeat, I think it's a good idea to have all the database objects scripted (and kept in source control). So I'd add the suggestion that you kill 2 birds with one stone - script the database, then search the generated sql scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this red-gate tool: [sql search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql_search/index.htm) Still in beta but it ought to work

Comment: awesome tool, tyvm it works at returning information pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have some `LF`, `CR/LF`s, or extra spaces in there that are preventing your search from working. Reduce your search string until you get a match (e.g., try just using the table name), or change it to: `%INSERT%SOMETHING%INTO%SOMETHING%`, etc.

Comment: It finds 1 instance of the table name... the SELECT that pulls the information back out of it, but it doesn't find the INSERT that is putting the information into it.

Comment: How do you know the `INSERT` statement is within the database and not coming from an application accessing the database?

Comment: There are no other applications accessing the database, other than the application I am working on.  All of the sql for this process is contained in stored procedures.

Comment: How are you determining that this statement is being run?

Comment: a procedure that happens after this process cannot run unless there is data in this table.